# Best way to move data between two pages in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

tl;dr - best practice for moving data between two pages in Svelte?

I have two pages, let's say First.svelte and Second.svelte.

In a traditional framework, I might create a form on First.svelte and then post it to Second.svelte. I can bind hidden input values on the First.svelte form and then post it to Second.svelte. I have found a lot of great information on how to manage the form locally to the page itself, but not on how to move data between pages.

I'm having a surprisingly hard time figuring out how the best way to read form data in a SvelteKit page. It looks like I could use get/setContext instead, or perhaps there is another option?

It also appears that form submission is often handled via an endpoint instead of just in the script tag at the top of the receiving page. Is that considered a SvelteKit best practice, or...?

I found this article and it made it look like the endpoint was more or less required. https://codechips.me/sveltekit-ssr-forms/

Is there a recommended/best practice/officially supported Svelte/SvelteKit solution for moving data between pages?

Comment: Keep in mind, often form submissions are "handled" in endpoints because either you are using a "traditional" form submit and are getting data from [formData](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints-body-parsing) or the submission needs to be entered into a database, external api, or something else that can't be exposed on the client side due to secrets or similar. "I have two pages, let's say First.svelte and Second.svelte.". Do you mean First has its own submission and Second has a different submission? It it something like a wizard multi step/page form?

Comment: Keep in mind, you can always just create a svelte store and access it from different pages to store data between pages. Maybe you could use something like [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/?starters=fullstack) to create an example of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question. Do you mean you want to persist data across pages?

Comment: tl;dr - yes, the answer is to use page endpoints (formerly called shadow endpoints).

Yes, I have a form on First.svelte that is (more or less) like the first step in a multi submit process - fill a bit of data on First.svelte, which then posts to Second.svelte to complete.

It took some fiddling to figure out how to a) do the post/submits, how the page endpoints inject values, and how to do error handling. Now that it's working it's actually very slick but the docs are virtually non-existent.

Hopefully will have a nice writeup to explain in the next few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use a form, you would handle it with an endpoint; but you could just use stores: if the user goes from one page to the next without refreshing the browser, it should stay there.

You can also look into persistent stores for more reliability if the user refreshes the page but simple stores should be enough.